# How to (Properly) add in each execution of a loop in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, google-chrome, parsing

So i'm attempting to write a google parser.
The idea of my tool is it takes search queries and searches google for them and returns URLs. It is working good so far but now im trying to set a page configuration and im having troubles, my code is:

```
const needle = require("needle") //for making get request
const sp = require("serp-parser") //for parsing data from the request
const queryup = "watch movies online free" //my search data
const query = encodeURI(queryup) //my search data so google can read it
var page = 0; //initializing the page counter
let pages = 5; //setting amount of pages to loop through
for (var i = 0; i < pages; i++) { //my loop
  needle.get(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${query}&start=${page}`, function(err, response){ //MY MAIN PROBLEM <<<--- The issue is its adding to the page value but its not effecting it here, why?
    page += 10 //adding to page value (every 10 page value is 1 extra page)
    console.log(`----- Page number: `+ page / 10+" -----") //logging the number of the page to confirm that it is indeed increasing the page value
    let results = response.body; //defining the body of my request
    parser = new sp.GoogleNojsSERP(results); //initializing the parser
    let parsed = parser.serp //parsing the body
    let objarray = parsed.organic; //parsed body (returns as an array of json objects)
    for (var i = 0; i < objarray.length; i++) { //loop the logging of each url
      let url = objarray[i].url //defining url
      console.log(url) //logging each url
    }
  });
}
```

without a billion comments:

```
const needle = require("needle") 
const sp = require("serp-parser") 
const queryup = "watch movies online free"
const query = encodeURI(queryup) 
var page = 0;
let pages = 5; 
for (var i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
  needle.get(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${query}&start=${page}`, function(err, response){ 


    //^^^^^ MY MAIN PROBLEM <<<--- The issue is its adding to the page value but its not effecting it here, why?



    page += 10 
    console.log(`----- Page number: `+ page / 10+" -----")
    let results = response.body;
    parser = new sp.GoogleNojsSERP(results);
    let parsed = parser.serp
    let objarray = parsed.organic;
    for (var i = 0; i < objarray.length; i++) {
      let url = objarray[i].url
      console.log(url)
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with async.
I'm not familiar with needle, but I know that external queries are basically never synchronous.

The problem you're experiencing is basically, the actual web query is happening after the loop first runs and has already incremented `page` to 50. Then, 5 queries are constructed, each one with page=50, because async is complicated and difficult to manage.

Under the hood, the engine is essentially doing literally everything else it can possibly do first, and THEN doing your web queries.

A trip through the `needle` npm docs tells me that you can use alternative syntax to get needle to return a promise instead, which can then be wrapped in an asynchronous function and managed through `await` to force synchronous behavior, which is what you're after:

```
const needle = require('needle');
const sp = require('serp-parser');
const queryup = 'watch movies online free';
const query = encodeURI(queryup);
let page = 0;
const pages = 5;

const googler = async function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
    try {
      const response = await needle('get', `https://www.google.com/search?q=${query}&start=${page}`);// MY MAIN PROBLEM <<<--- The issue is its adding to the page value but its not effecting it here, why?
      console.log('----- Page number: ' + page / 10 + ' -----');
      const results = await response.body;
      const parser = new sp.GoogleNojsSERP(results);
      const parsed = parser.serp;
      const objarray = parsed.organic;
      for (let i = 0; i < objarray.length; i++) {
        const url = objarray[i].url;
        console.log(url);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    page += 10;
  }
};

googler();
```

The key differences:

1. Per the `needle` docs, rather than the request method being a method on the `needle` object, it's instead the first argument you pass directly to invoking `needle` itself as a function.
2. When you manage promises with `await`, a rejected promise throws an error that should be caught with a traditional try/catch block; I've done that here. Though, if `needle` is anything like `node-fetch` it probably basically never throws errors, but it's good practice.

One of my extensions automatically changed your `var` declarations to `let` and not-reassigned `let` declarations to `const`; you're welcome to change them back.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic asynchronous problem. Add another `console.log()` immediately before the `needle.get()` call (and after the `for` statement) and you will see what is going wrong: All of the `needle.get()` calls execute *before* any of the callbacks where you do the `page += 10`. Then, *after* the `for` loop completes, all of the callbacks are executed. But it is too late for this to have any effect on the `start=` parameter.

One way to fix this could be to move the body of this `for` loop (the `needle.get()` and its callback) into a separate function. Initialize your variables and call this function once. Then at the end of the callback, do your `page += 10` and update any other variables you need to, and call this function again from there *if* there are more pages left that you want to load. If you have completed all of the pages, then don't make that call. The `for` loop is not needed with this technique.

Or, you could keep your current code but move the `page += 10` *after* the callback but still inside the outer `for` loop. That way this variable will be incremented as you expect. I don't necessarily recommend this, as Google may get unhappy about receiving the `get` requests so rapidly and may start blocking your calls or throwing CAPTCHAs at you.

There may be an issue of whether this kind of scraping is allowed by Google's Terms of Service, but I will leave that question to you and your legal advisors.

Also, I would avoid using `var` anywhere. Use `const` or `let` instead, and prefer `const` over `let` except when you need to reassign the variable.

One tip: in most cases where you use a numeric `for` loop to iterate over an array, the code will be cleaner if you use a `for..of` loop. For example, this bit of code:

```
let parsed = parser.serp
let objarray = parsed.organic;
for (var i = 0; i < objarray.length; i++) {
  let url = objarray[i].url
  console.log(url)
}
```

could be more simply written as:

```
for (const result of parser.serp.organic) {
  console.log(result.url)
}
```

(I know that is just a bit of debug code, but this is a good habit to get into.)

Finally, watch your indentation and be sure to indent nested blocks or functions. I took the liberty of adding some indentation for you.